# update delete column to 1 where review id is 'x' using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I've asked a similar question before however i've done alot of changes to my script and my question is now different to my last question. So now i've done these changes this should all work fine however it isn't.

I've basically got user reviews where a user can delete or approve reviews. I am focusing purely on the delete function at the moment.

We pull the reviews through in reviews.php and a the user can click delete which points to delete_review.php which then runs the sql function stored in functions.php.

I've listed the exact code layed how it works below but besides me spending ages trying to work out why it won't work i can't figure it out. When we click delete it links to delete_review.php but it won't find the review id which is the id of the review in which to delete.

Can someone please show me how i can fix this. thank you.

review.php

```
<?php
    $reviews_set = get_new_reviews();
    while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set)) {
?>

    <div class="prof-content-pend-reviews" id="reviews">
    <div class="pend-review-content">
    <?php echo "{$reviews['content']}"; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="message_pic">
    <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\"><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\" src=\"data/photos/{$reviews['from_user_id']}/_default.jpg\" /></a>";?>
    </div>

    <div class="forum-text">
    <?php echo "Posted by {$reviews['display_name']}"; ?> <?php echo "".$age." days ago"; ?>
    </div>

    <a href="includes/delete_review.php?review=<?php echo $reviews['review']; ?>"><div class="delete"></div></a>
    </div>

    <? }  ?>
```

function.php

```
function delete_review($review, $user) {
                        global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
                        $query = "UPDATE ptb_reviews
                                    SET deleted='1'
                                    WHERE id=$review 
                                    AND to_user_id=$user";
            mysql_query($query, $connection);
                }   


function get_new_reviews() {
            global $connection;
            global $_SESSION;
            $query = "SELECT r.from_user_id, p.display_name, r.content, r.id reviews_id, r.date_added
                        FROM ptb_reviews r, ptb_profiles p
                        WHERE r.to_user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']."
                        AND r.deleted = '0'
                        AND r.read_review = '0'
                        AND p.user_id = r.from_user_id
                        ORDER BY r.date_added DESC ";


                        $reviews_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($reviews_set);
            return $reviews_set;
        }
```

delete_review.php

```
    <?php
    require_once("session.php"); 
    require_once("functions.php");
    require('_config/connection.php');
    delete_review ($_GET['review'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
    ?>
```

Comment: The fact that this is ripe for SQL injection aside, have you verified that `$reviews['review']` (and subsequently `$_GET['review']`) is actually set?

Comment: well i'm still learning php and mysql, how could i check if they are set?

Comment: No need for `global $_SESSION`. it is a superglobal, and available in all scopes..

Comment: Like you had in your earlier question, you should be calling `(int)` or `is_numeric()` on `$_GET['review']` to cast to an integer before using in your query.  What is the type of `$user`? Is it a string value or integer?

Comment: @JohnSimmons - An easy way is to simply `echo $review;` in your `delete_review` function (comment out the rest for now).

Comment: @SenorAmor - Well i tried to get rid of the rest and just echo $review; but that doesn't work either.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means nothing to me.  You'll need to be more specific on *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: You should check the output of the function `get_new_reviews()`

Comment: `get_new_reviews()` show us this function

Comment: @goodmood - added to functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this:

```
 $reviews['review']
```

maybe should be this:

```
 $reviews['reviews_id']
```

not sure, your code needs some improvement. You should really look into mysqli or PDO. All of this could easily be done with a simple class.

Comment: ok and what about in delete_review.php where it's: delete_review ($_GET['review'], $_SESSION['user_id']); should that be  ($_GET['reviews_id'] aswell?

Comment: Yes I believe so. without seeing all of your code this would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

**1-** check if you make session start  `session_start();` in the begining of your `review.php` file

**2-** look at this

```
   $query = "SELECT r.from_user_id, p.display_name, r.content, r.id reviews_id, r.date_adde
                                                                   ^--------what this space ?
```

**3-** try to do `global $_SESSION['user_id']` in your function.

**4** be sure if its `$reviews` or `$reviews_id` here as `ROY Finley` mentioned

```
   <a href="includes/delete_review.php?review=<?php echo $reviews['review']
                                                                      ^----------here
```

Comment: $_SESSION is a super global, no need to declare it.